# Firefox 80.0.1 Blocking Javascript Redirects

Tags: javascript, firefox

Starting with Firefox 80.0.1 the JavaScript redirects I am using no longer work. I use these when I redirect users between pages on the same site. Anyone know how to get redirects to work again in Firefox 80.0.1?

This is a line of code that worked, but no longer does in 80.0.1.

```
window.location = "home";
```

Comment: What is the current behavior that you are experiencing (logs, errors, etc.) since Firefox Dev works correctly using the Web Console, MDN also states that it may not work with some CORS settings.

Comment: No errors of any kind displayed in any of the logs. I have dug through the browser settings, but can't find anything related to this.

Comment: What I meant was https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS, though this usually generates an error, the other thing to check is whether `window.location = "home"` is actually called - though that is a stab in the dark.

Comment: Got ya. Yeah, I don't think this is the issue, because it is the same domain and same directory even.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/redirect

```
const myRequest = new Request("flowers.jpg");
const myCred = myRequest.redirect;
```

Comment: Note that linked content is not considered part of the answer and that code-only answers are usually perceived as less helpful than answer according to [answer], i.e. with an explanation how the solution works and why it helps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).